# Run Script on startup on AWS Ec2 Ubuntu 1404 Server

Tags: 14.04, bash, startup, cron, aws

I Need to start services such as elasticsearch, kafka on boot time of the Ec2 instance

I Have tried @reboot on crontab but something is going wrong

Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

nohup /home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-2.3.4/bin/elasticsearch &
```

Crontab entry:

```
@reboot sh /home/abhijeet/startServices.sh
```

I dont know where I am going wrong

Comment: you are missing a `#` in the shebang line. is that a typo?

Comment: @heemayl sorry its a typo while posting the question. In actual script its there

Comment: Just do `@reboot /home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-2.3.4/bin/elasticsearch` , this would be synonymous to what you are doing now.

Comment: You require something similar to [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32300410/2626653) to add it on to startup. Also, there's a [**reason**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html) why **Elasticsearch** is not fired-up at startup on Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cron` runs shells in a modified environment with a minimal `PATH` and presumably `/usr/bin` not present there so `/usr/bin/nohup` is not being found.

You can:

- add `/usr/bin` to the `PATH`, rather than modifying your `crontab`'s one, you should add this at the top of the script:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  export PATH="$PATH":/usr/bin
  nohup /home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-2.3.4/bin/elasticsearch &
  ```
- Use absolute path to `nohup`:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  /usr/bin/nohup /home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-2.3.4/bin/elasticsearch &
  ```

Note that, according to the `crontab` entry, you are executing the script as an argument to `sh` (`dash`) while having an exactly same shebang. In this case this doesn't make any difference but be careful about this if the shebang is different. Usually one would make the script executable and use shebang to indicate the desired interpreter.

---

Now, **the most important part**. `cron` runs all given jobs in their respective subshells and spawns these subshell parallel (non-blocking) i.e. runs jobs in parallel manner. So you don't need the `nohup` and backgrounding (`&`), just do (based on your example, `/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-2.3.4/bin/elasticsearch` is executable):

```
@reboot /home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-2.3.4/bin/elasticsearch
```